# Using multiple parameters for filtering data in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I'm working on a library project, where you should be able to filter books by publisher, category, stars, sites, etc.

I have come up with a solution however it consists of multiple if statements, and I don't find it very scalable if I would like to add more filters in the future.

This is one of the methods in my `BookController` which handles it:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(int? id, string title, string forlag, int rating)
{
    //Search by title given by category id
    var list = (from ep in _db.Books
                join e in _db.BookCategories 
                on ep.BookID equals e.BookID
                where e.CategoryID == id && ep.Title.Contains($"{title}")
                select new Book
                {
                    BookID = ep.BookID,
                    Title = ep.Title,
                    Author = ep.Author,
                    Isbn = ep.Isbn,
                    Publisher = ep.Publisher,
                    Sites = ep.Sites,
                    ReleaseDate = ep.ReleaseDate,
                    Summary = ep.Summary,
                    Picture = ep.Picture,
                    AddedDate = ep.AddedDate,
                    Stars = ep.Stars,
                }).ToList();

    var queryID = (from u in _db.Books
                    join e in _db.BookCategories
                    on u.BookID equals e.BookID
                    where e.CategoryID == id
                    select new Book
                    {
                        BookID = u.BookID,
                        Title = u.Title,
                        Author = u.Author,
                        Isbn = u.Isbn,
                        Publisher = u.Publisher,
                        Sites = u.Sites,
                        ReleaseDate = u.ReleaseDate,
                        Summary = u.Summary,
                        Picture = u.Picture,
                        AddedDate = u.AddedDate,
                        Stars = (from c in _db.bookComments where c.BookID == u.BookID && c.IsApproved == true select c.Stars).Average(),
                    }).ToList();

    var queryID2 = (from u in _db.Books
                    select new Book
                    {
                        BookID = u.BookID,
                        Title = u.Title,
                        Author = u.Author,
                        Isbn = u.Isbn,
                        Publisher = u.Publisher,
                        Sites = u.Sites,
                        ReleaseDate = u.ReleaseDate,
                        Summary = u.Summary,
                        Picture = u.Picture,
                        AddedDate = u.AddedDate,
                        Stars = (from c in _db.bookComments where c.BookID == u.BookID && c.IsApproved == true select c.Stars).Average(),
                    }).ToList();


    var sortedID = queryID.Where(o => o.Stars >= rating);
    var sortedID2 = queryID2.Where(o => o.Stars >= rating);


    //Search by title if category id equals 0
    var bookList = _db.Books.Where(o => o.Title.Contains($"{title}"));

    //Sort by category, publisher & star rating
    if (id > 0 && forlag != null && rating > 0)
    {
        var newListus = sortedID.Where(o => o.Publisher == forlag);
        return View(newListus);
    }

    //Sort by publisher & star rating
    if (id == 0 && forlag != null && rating > 0)
    {
        var peter = sortedID2.Where(o => o.Publisher == forlag);
        return View(peter);
    }

    //Sort by category & publisher
    if (id > 0 && forlag != null)
    {
        var newList = list.Where(o => o.Publisher == forlag);
        return View(newList);
    }

    //Sort by category & star rating
    if (id > 0 && rating > 0)
    {
        return View(sortedID);
    }

    //Sort by star rating
    if (id == 0 && rating > 0)
    {
        return View(sortedID2);
    }

    //Sort by publisher
    if (id == 0 && forlag != null)
    {
        var bookListSorted = _db.Books.Where(o => o.Publisher == forlag);
        return View(bookListSorted);
    }
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return View(bookList);
    }

    return View(list);
}
```

Any more scalable and easier solution would be appreciated. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Matteo

Comment: This query can be simplified. Can you translate your comments? I'm not good in Danish and many people here. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @SvyatoslavDanyliv the comments should be translated now! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ's feature query composition.

I Have defined intermediate anonymous class to handle Book and it's stars.

```cs
public IActionResult Index(int? id, string title, string forlag, int rating)
{
    // filterout by title and set stars to default value
    var books = _db.Books
        .Where(b => b.Title.Contains(title))
        .Select(b => new { Book = b, Stars = 0.0 });

    var isStarsDefined  = false;

    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        //Search by title given by category id and assign category's Starts
        books = 
            from b in books
            join c in _db.BookCategories on b.Book.BookID equals c.BookID
            where c.CategoryID == id
            select new { Book = b.Book, Stars = c.Starts };

        isStarsDefined  = true;
    }

    // additional filter by publisher
    if (forlag != null)
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.Book.Publisher == forlag);
    }

    // well probably for result we need stars
    if (!isStarsDefined)
    {
        books = books.Select(b  => new 
        { 
            Book = b.Book, 
            Stars = _db.bookComments
                .Where(c => c.BookID == b.Book.BookID && c.IsApproved == true)
                .Select(c => c.Stars)
                .Average()
        })
    }

    // filter by rating
    if (rating > 0)
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.Stars >= rating);
    }

    // make final projection to DTO
    var result = books
        .Select(b => new Book
        {
            BookID = b.Book.BookID,
            Title = b.Book.Title,
            Author = b.Book.Author,
            Isbn = b.Book.Isbn,
            Publisher = b.Book.Publisher,
            Sites = b.Book.Sites,
            ReleaseDate = b.Book.ReleaseDate,
            Summary = b.Book.Summary,
            Picture = b.Book.Picture,
            AddedDate = b.Book.AddedDate,
            Stars = b.Stars
        })
        .ToList();

    result View(result);
}
```

Note, that I have written everything from memory and there can be minor compilation issues. Also if you use `ToList` in the middle you will fail, everything should work via `IQueryable`.

Comment: Hey! This looks great, however what is the "e.bookID". I get this error: 
Error CS1938The name 'e' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

Comment: Fixed, i’m not compiler ;)